# Is Resharper confused by Aliases used for Assemblies in Using directives?

Tags: office-interop, using-directives, resharper-9.2

I noticed this in my .cs file, which looks like I might be "mixing metaphors" or at least being redundant by having both "*Microsoft.Office.Interop*" and "*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel*" in my list of usings directives:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MSExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Resharper, when Inspecting for Code Issues in Solution, normally flags unused using directives, but in this case it peeped not a peep regarding "using MSExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop;" even though when I commented it out to see what would happen, the solution compiles fine - so it has fooled Resharper, I guess. So does this mean this is a known "hole in Resharper's swing" and I should suspect the necessity of any aliased using directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, this option in R# Options > C# > Namespace Imports is enabled:

> Do not remove using alias directives if alias name differs from the imported type name

Because if the alias name is non-trivial you may have a reason outside of R#'s knowledge to have it.

Disabling the option will show the directive as redundant.